# Else if calculation not working, program works if i remove else if and have only 1 formula

Tags: quote, instant

I have been tyring to create a form that a customer could enter the size of their yard and get a quote.  If i only use one formula with no if else it works fine, but when I add the other formula options to create accurate pricing I get no results.  I have read multiple suggestions and have tried any i could fine with no avail.

```
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="Instant Quote">
    <table border="1" width="300" height="200" cellpadding="10"            cellspacing="3">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">
                <h1>Instant Quote</h1>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>  
            <th>
                <h3>Square Footage of Yard</h3>
            </th>
            <th>
                <input type="number" name="INPUT1" id="input" onchange="calculate();"/>
            </th>    

        </tr>
        <tr>  
            <th>
                <h3>Cost per treatment</h3>
            </th>
            <th>
                <input type="number" name="OUTPUT1" id="output">
            </th>    

        </tr>
        <tr> 



        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function calculate() {
    var USERINPUT1 = document.TESTING.INPUT1.value,
    if (USERINPUT1 >=0 && USERINPUT1 <= 5000) {
    RESULT = (USERINPUT1*.005) + 25;
  } else if (USERINPUT1 >=5001 && USERINPUT1 <= 10000) {
   RESULT = (USERINPUT1*.0045) + 25;
  } else {
    RESULT = (USERINPUT1*.004) + 25;
  }  
   document.TESTING.OUTPUT1.value = RESULT;
}



</script>

<body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- At the end of you USERINPUT1 declaration you probably want a semi-colon instead of a comma.
- document.TESTING.INPUT1 doesn't exist on the DOM, you can probably use document.getElementById("input") instead.

```js
function calculate() {
    var USERINPUT1 = document.getElementById("input").value;
    if (USERINPUT1 >=0 && USERINPUT1 <= 5000) {
    RESULT = (USERINPUT1*.005) + 25;
  } else if (USERINPUT1 >=5001 && USERINPUT1 <= 10000) {
   RESULT = (USERINPUT1*.0045) + 25;
  } else {
    RESULT = (USERINPUT1*.004) + 25;
  }  
   document.getElementById("output").value = RESULT;
}
```

```html
<form name="Instant Quote">
    <table border="1" width="300" height="200" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="3">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">
                <h1>Instant Quote</h1>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>  
            <th>
                <h3>Square Footage of Yard</h3>
            </th>
            <th>
                <input type="number" name="INPUT1" id="input" onchange="calculate();"/>
            </th>    

        </tr>
        <tr>  
            <th>
                <h3>Cost per treatment</h3>
            </th>
            <th>
                <input type="number" name="OUTPUT1" id="output">
            </th>    

        </tr>
        <tr> 

        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  The comma seemed to be my major problem.  It has been 15 years since I have worked on html.  It is amazing how one small error can be overlooked.